Can an individual do four salutations to exit prayer, Maliki madhab do three sometimes?
When praying alone we greet the Angel's who record our deeds. Can an individual do four salutations to exit prayer by greeting the guardian Angel's too?
One to the right, one to the front, one to the left, one to the back
Maliki madhab do three salutations to exit prayer sometimes

There's no recorded textual backup for a fourth salutation nor saluting the angels so doing this is bida'ah (an innovation).

@Medi1Saif Abu Hafs ibn al-Muslim – one of our companions – said: He should intend by the first salaam to exit the prayer and he should intend by the second to greet the recording angels and the members of the congregation, if he is the imam, and to respond to the imam and the recording angels if he is praying behind an imam."(Al-Mughni, 1/326 )

I read a report more than a decade ago that we greet Angel's, i cant locate it. The above is the closest I could get,
